Do vtails need twin horizontal trim tabs?
Do vtails need twin horizontal trim tabs?
As vtail aircraft don't have a separate horizontal tail, do they need a trim tab on both rudervators?

Not necessarily.  Although the well-known Beechcraft Bonanza has twin tabs,

Sometimes one trim tab, usually the left one, will be offset slightly while the right tab is flush with the control surface. Slightly "tweaking" the left trim tab angle relative to the right's was a common means of adjusting the rig when the airplane was first flown at the factory as part of production.

the Sonex Waiex homebuilt needs only one:

I have the idea of installing one on EACH ruddervator. For pitch, they are moved together, and perhaps for yaw trim they are moved opposite.

...

I considered this on my Waiex project but rejected it. ...I would have to design some sort of 'mixer' to provide proportional tab input.

...

The Dial-A-Trim system that Sonex sells does a good job for "elevator" trim on the Waiex, is pretty fool proof, is ultra reliable, is cheap, and is light in weight.


No, you can get by with a bungee device in the elevator control circuit "upstream" of the mixer to do the job. Basically a spring that applies stick forward for aft pressure for you, and will tend to hold the surfaces at a given position, for the elevator command part, when you hands are  off the stick (you could put the bungee right at the base of the stick if you wanted). More or less the same as a bungee trim for a conventional tail.
If you use tabs for pitch trim only, you will have one on each surface and each tab move the same amount as if you had a horizontal tail with a tab on each surface. If you wanted to use the tabs for both pitch and rudder trim, you'd have to design a mixing mechanism that would do the same sort of thing as the main control mixer, where moving the rudder trim control creates a yaw bias, and the pitch trim control creates a pitch bias in the gearing of the tabs.
One advantage of tabs is you can build an anti-servo function into the tab's operating geometry that allows you to tailor the control feedback beyond the feedback you get with the surfaces alone. If you wanted to use an "all-flying" V tail, you would have to use tabs that provide both a trimming function and an anti-servo function. The Austria glider is a classic example of this. It has all-flying V tail surfaces (no fixed stabilizers) and large anti-servo tabs that provide for both trim and pitch stability and feedback forces. 
If it was for an ultralight, I would just use a bungee spring in the elevator control circuit upstream of the mixer. And a regular tail configuration. The V tail has always been a kind of dead end concept.
